# Is regression towards the mean happening when we use a control group?

Tags: r, regression, variance, lme4-nlme, mean

I have a subset of 40000 participants in my study. From those I would like to study those with higher weight longitudinally, and compare them with those with healthy weight.
I observe, that those with high weight get better over time in their fat, while the healthy got slightly worse.
This is a bit counter-intuitive, one hypothesis is that regression towards the mean is playing a role. However, it can also happen that my subset of obese people got better over time.

I am working with Linear mixed effects models with fixed and random effects.
In a LME (and other models) the categorical coefficients (weight = obese, healthy) compare one against the other. Therefore in this case I am comparing Obese people against Healthy.

**My question is:** Is regression to the mean possible to happen in this particular problem? In my opinion, NO. As I understand, regression to the mean can only happen if you compare visit 2 to visit 1 in the same group. But in this case I compare Obese against the reference group that is Healthy.

Am I right?
Thanks

```
lme(fixed = fat ~ weight + visit  + visit*weight, random = ~ visit| participantID, data = df,control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"))
```

Comment: Presumably fat and weight and obesity are positively correlated both for the population and for individuals over time.  If these fluctuate over time for individuals, and you separate the population at some point in time, it seems reasonable to expect  there will be some regression to the mean at later points in time, even without the intervention.  Your control group should include individuals similar to those in your intervention group.

Comment: Fat is a variable that measures fat in one particular organ. Just for clarification I don't have any intervention group. I just observe over time people who at baseline were obese and people who at baseline had a normal BMI. So the comparison is obese over time Vs healthy over time. None of them got an intervention. Do you think this still shows regression to the mean?

Comment: Yes - I would expect some regression to the mean over time: some heavier people will lose weight and some lighter people will gain weight as part of normal fluctuations

Comment: and how would you control/account/correct for this?